# How to dynamically add a row without "Requested unknown parameter" error

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatables

I am new to DataTables and I am having problems in dynamically adding a new row to the datatable.

Here is my initialization:

```
table = $("#college-list").DataTable({
    'ajax': {
       'url': 'admin/get_college',
       'type': 'GET'
    },
    'columns': [
       { 'data': 'college_abbrev', "bSortable": true  },
       { 'data': 'college_name' , "bSortable": true },
       {
         "mData": null,
         "bSortable": false,
         "mRender": function(data, type, college) {
            return '<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit-college table-condensed">Edit</button>'
                   +'<button data-id="' + college.college_id  + '" type="button" class="delete-college btn btn-primary table-condensed" href="">Delete</button>';
          }
       }
    ]
});
```

Here is the sample code that I am using when adding a new row (`ca`, `cn`, and `college_id` are variables):

```
table.row.add( [
    {
       "college_abbrev": ca,
       "college_name": cn,
       "button":'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary edit-college table-condensed">Edit</button>'
                +'<button data-id="' + college_id  + '" type="button" class="delete-college btn btn-primary table-condensed" href="">Delete</button>'
    }
]).draw();
```

It creates a row but the columns are empty except for the buttons and it gives the following error:

> DataTables warning: table id=college-list - Requested unknown
>   parameter 'college_abbrev' for row 17

How do you properly add a new row?

Comment: before adding just check what is the value of `ca`? I feel that is not proper here!

Comment: Check the value of `ca` buddy!! `Console.log(ca)`

Comment: I have a valid value for ca. Gyrocode pointed out that I was passing an array of objects instead of just a simple object. But thanks for the tip anyway.

Comment: Anyways!! Happy coding.. :)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Use the code below instead:

```
table.row.add({
   "college_abbrev": ca,
   "college_name": cn,
   "college_id": college_id
}).draw();
```

You're getting "Requested unknown parameter" error because you're passing array of objects to `row.add()`, where you should pass simple object instead, see [row.add()](https://datatables.net/reference/api/row.add%28%29) for more information.

Also you don't need to construct a button in a call to `row.add()`. Your `mRender` function will take care of it for you. Instead you need to pass `college_id` because `mRender` will need it to produce a button.

Generally, you need to pass row data to `row.add()` in the same format your Ajax script `admin/get_college` uses.

Comment: I don't think this will answer OPs question because if you see the error and detailed description of the error **[here](https://www.datatables.net/manual/tech-notes/4)** it says OP is missing a `parameter` or not implementing proper format of the `parameter`! with your code it just appends `college_id` to the last column whereas it has to be buttons!!

Comment: @GuruprasadRao, render function will take of producing the button.

Comment: That might be but the issue here he is getting at the very beginning of the assigment of `ca` parameter!! You might be right!! OP has to try and give his feedback!!

Comment: It worked. So the only problem is the third parameter?

Comment: @Compiler, added more details to the answer. The problem is in using array of objects instead of plain object and missing `college_id` property.

Comment: Oh. I just copied the example from here.
https://datatables.net/examples/api/add_row.html
I did not see the one that you linked. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

DataTable `table.row.add()` doesn't seem to accept an `array` anymore and now expects an `object`. I had to define `columns` during the datatable  initialization, and change `row.add()` from `.add([val1, val2])` to `.add({"v1": val1, "v2": val2})`.

old way:

```js
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#valueTable').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "pageLength": -1,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [-1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
            ["All", 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
        ],
        // Sort by val1, then by val2
        "order": [[0, "desc"], [1, "desc"]]
    });
});


var jRow = table.row
    .add([
        val1,
        val2
    ])
.draw()
.nodes()
.to$();
```

new way:

```js
var table;
$(document).ready(function() {
    table = $('#valueTable').DataTable({
        "paging": true,
        "pageLength": -1,
        "lengthMenu": [
            [-1, 5, 10, 25, 50, 100],
            ["All", 5, 10, 25, 50, 100]
        ],
        // Sort by val1, then by val2
        "order": [[0, "desc"], [1, "desc"]],
        'columns': [
            { 'data': '1', "bSortable": true },
            { 'data': '2', "bSortable": true },
        ]
    });
});

var jRow = table.row
    .add({
        "1": val1,
        "2": val2
    })
.draw()
.nodes()
.to$();
```